# Issues When Calling a Method in Android

Tags: java, android, methods, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a NullPointerException but I'm not sure why since this code should work correctly. Below is the calling method where I need a JSONObject to be created from a file on the 'raw' folder.

```
JSONObject currenciesJsonObject = MiscHelper.getJsonObjectFromResource(R.raw.app_currencies, getActivity());
```

Below is the full class file which is extended by DialogFragment:

```
    package uk.co.example.calculator.ui.fragments;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import uk.co.example.calculator.R;
import uk.co.example.calculator.adapters.SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter;
import uk.co.example.calculator.ui.activities.DividerItemDecoration;
import uk.co.example.calculator.ui.activities.ExchangeRate;
import uk.co.example.utils.MiscHelper;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CurrencyConverterDialogFrag extends android.app.DialogFragment {

    // Declare UI elements
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public CurrencyConverterDialogFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_currency_converter_dialog_calc, new LinearLayout(getActivity()), false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        initializeRecyclerView();

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle("Choose currency");

        dialog.setContentView(view);


        return dialog;
    }



        JSONObject currenciesJsonObject = MiscHelper.getJsonObjectFromResource(R.raw.app_currencies, getActivity());




    private ArrayList<ExchangeRate> getSampleArrayList() {
        ArrayList<ExchangeRate> items = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            items.add(new ExchangeRate(currenciesJsonObject.getJSONObject("GBP").getString("name"), "Valyria"));
            items.add(new ExchangeRate("Rob Stark", "Winterfell"));
            items.add(new ExchangeRate("Jon Snow", "Castle Black"));
            items.add(new ExchangeRate("Tyrion Lanister", "King's Landing"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return items;
    }

        private void initializeRecyclerView() {

        // Setup layout manager for items
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        // Control orientation of the items
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        //Customize the position you want to default scroll to
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);

        // Attach layout manager to the RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // allows for optimizations if all item views are of the same size:
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        bindDataToAdapter();
    }

    private void bindDataToAdapter() {
        // Bind adapter to recycler view object
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(getSampleArrayList()));
    }


}
```

Below is the method in the MiscHelper class where the exception occurs:

```
     public static JSONObject getJsonObjectFromResource(int resource, Context context) {

        // PROBLEM OCCURS ON THIS NEXT LINE AS STATED BY THE LOGCAT. LINE:252
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resource);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        String jsonString = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            while (( line = r.readLine() ) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append( line );
            }
            jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("GetJsonFromResource", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }


        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("GetJsonFromResource", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

Below is the LogCat with the exception:

```
    07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793): Process: uk.co.codepix.calculator, PID: 6793
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at uk.co.codepix.utils.MiscHelper.getJsonObjectFromResource(MiscHelper.java:252)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at uk.co.codepix.calculator.ui.fragments.CurrencyConverterDialogFrag.<init>(CurrencyConverterDialogFrag.java:56)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at uk.co.codepix.calculator.ui.fragments.CurrencyConverterInputCalcFrag$1.onClick(CurrencyConverterInputCalcFrag.java:73)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-12 12:38:01.999: E/AndroidRuntime(6793):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any detailed explanation as to how I should fix the problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Apparently, context is null. So getActivity() might return null. Need to see more code, where do you call this method from?

Comment: where you called `getJsonObjectFromResource(....)` ?

Comment: Where is the call to getJsonObjectFromResource located? is it inside an activity ?

Comment: Hi @IgorFilippov, good question. So the method is being called from a DialogFragment inside a Fragment. I think you are correct that context is probably returning null but I'm trying to call getBaseContext() and getApplicationContext() but both are coming up as being undefined methods when used on the method.

Comment: Hi @MD, I just posted a comment to Igor which may explain the situation better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see you initialise your variable `currenciesJsonObject` in an instance initialiser, which means by the time you do it, `Fragment` isn't attached to `Activity`.

Move this call:

```
MiscHelper.getJsonObjectFromResource(R.raw.app_currencies, getActivity());
```

to a lifecycle callback where `getActivity` won't return null. `onAttach()` or `onCreate()` might be a good place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here is just a quick input:
Try using `getBaseContext()` instead of `getActivity()`.

`getBaseContext()` is a method of the ContextWrapper. This ContextWrapper can be modified without changing the original context. In Javadoc: "Proxying implementation of Context that simply delegates all of its calls to another Context. Can be subclassed to modify behavior without changing the original Context."

There is also one more method that could work:
`getApplicationContext()`. This method on the other hand returns the application context (of the entire app life cycle). This means that when `onDestroy()` has been called, this method returns null.

Hope it helps.

Comment: and can you explain why using getBaseContext will solve the issie?

Comment: getBaseContext might solve it. There is no guarantee for that, because I don't know where @CBA110 calls `getJsonObjectFromResource()`

Comment: Hi @guicor, this method is being called from a DialogFragment inside a Fragment. I'm trying to call getBaseContext() and getApplicationContext() but both are coming up as being undefined methods when used on the method in question.

Comment: @CBA110 If you are on `Fragment` then used `getActivity()` for Accessing `Context` also move your code  `JSONObject currenciesJsonObject = MiscHelper.getJsonObjectFromResource(R.raw.app_currencies, getActivity());`
 inside `onCreateDialog(..)`

Comment: Hi @MD, I just posted the full class file for more detail on how the method is being called.

Comment: I agree with @MD that  you have to move your code. But depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could also put it in `getSampleArrayList()` as it is the only function that uses the variable `currenciesJsonObject `